# Quality Center V11 Script Stats using Java and COM4J

Tags: java, hp-quality-center, com4j

I am trying to access ALM V11 (QC) Test Script details like Passed/No Run for particular project using Java but i am getting null. Can someone please help me on this?

Error I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.testpack.HPTest2.main(HPTest2.java:53)
```

Code I use to connect

```
        ITDConnection itd=ClassFactory.createTDConnection();
        System.out.println("Test1.1:"+ itd.connected());
        itd.initConnectionEx(url);
        System.out.println("Test1:"+ itd.connected());
        itd.connectProjectEx(domain,project,username,password);


        ITestFactory testFactory;
        //ITSTest2 testFactory;
        ITDFilter2 filterF;
        IList executinList;

        testFactory=(itd.testFactory()).queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
        //testFactory=(ITestFactory)itd.testFactory().queryInterface(ITestFactory.class);
        filterF=testFactory.fields().queryInterface(ITDFilter2.class);
        String query="\"Passed\"";
        filterF.filter("TC_STATUS",query);
        executinList=filterF.newList();
```

I was trying this my comparing the VBScript I have

```
Set tdc = CreateObject("tdapiole80.tdconnection")
tdc.InitConnection serverName, domainName
tdc.ConnectProject projectName, projUserName, projPassword

'Get the test factory filter
Set TestSetFact = tdc.TSTestFactory
'TestSetFact.AddItem()
Set TestSetFilter = TestSetFact.Filter
stemp = ApplicationName
appsplit = Split(ApplicationName, "or")

irowtemp = 18
'----------------------------------------------------

'--------------------------------
For iLoop = 0 To UBound(appsplit)
    TestSetFilter.Filter("TS_USER_06") = appsplit(iLoop)

    If initiativeName <> "" Then
        TestSetFilter.Filter("TS_USER_04") = initiativeName
    End If
    TestSetFilter.Filter("TC_STATUS") = "Passed"


    Sheet1.Cells(irowtemp, 2).Value = Trim(appsplit(iLoop))
```

Answer (score 3):

The Com4jObject.queryInterface() method returns null, if the wrapped COM object is not of that type.

It's probably just autocompletion, that messed up your code, but you should use

```
filterF=testFactory.filter().queryInterface(ITDFilter2.class);
```

To get the filter, instead of fields().